# Связка Sqlite3+python+ pyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Уважаемые знатоки, имеются следующие файлы:

db.py:

```
import sqlite3
import apsw

class BotDB():
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.db=sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cur=self.db.cursor()


    def drop_db(self):
        result_drop_db=self.cur.execute("DROP table IF EXISTS tovarniye_ostatki")       


    def create_db(self,):
        result_create_db=self.cur.execute("CREATE virtual table IF NOT EXISTS                                                                     
                                          tovarniye_ostatki 
                                          USING FTS5 (nazvanie_tovara, ostatok)")


    def add_goods(self):
        file='domstroy.csv'
        with open (file,'r', encoding="utf8",) as file:
            for row in file:   
                self.cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tovarniye_ostatki VALUES 
                                             (?,?)",row.split(";"),)
        return self.db.commit()


    def good_exists(self, user_request):
        user_request=self.user_request
        result_goods_exists=self.cur.execute(f"SELECT ostatki, nazvanie_tovara  FROM  
                                 tovarniye_ostatki WHERE nazvanite_tovara MATCH (?)",)
                                 
        return result_goods       
          

    def close(self):
        self.db.close()
```

main.py:

```
from db import BotDb

file=''   
@bot.message_handler()
def send_docs(message):
    if message.text=='1':
        file=open(r"D:\Proyekt\domstroy_1.csv",'rb')
    
    elif message.text=='2':
        file=open(r"D:\Proyekt\domstroy_2.csv",'rb')
    else:
        db_file='qoldiqlar1.db'
        BotDB(db_file).drop_db()
        BotDB(db_file).create_db()
        BotDB(db_file).add_goods()
        print(BotDB(db_file).good_exists(message.text))
bot.send_document(message.chat.id, file)
```

После запуска получаю исключение:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file' referenced before assignment.

Я хочу чтобы показались все товары которые содержать message.text.
Подскажите пожалуйста, где я допускаю ошибку.
Спасибо всем.

Comment: прощу помощь у знатоков.

Comment: @oleksandrigo, можете помочь с этим вопросом?. спасибо
https://pastebin.com/FrJe2YGV

Comment: А товары у вас где? Немного непонятно. Из БД нужно или откуда?

Comment: Надо вытащить из sqlite3

Comment: В методе `good_exists` в `cur.execute` добавьте кортеж с `user_request` после строки SQL запроса. А для чего Вам, кстати, `user_request=self.user_request` ?